# Not publish messages to RabbitMQ after commit or rollback

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I've got a problem with publish messages to RabbitMQ. Our application must work in transactional layer.

But, i don't understand one case: If I firstly start transaction and commit it, all next messages don't published to RabbitMQ.

```
$connection = new \AMQPConnection([
    'host'     => 'rabbitmq',
    'port'     => 5672,
    'login'    => 'guest',
    'password' => 'guest',
]);

$connection->connect();

$channel = new \AMQPChannel($connection);

$exchange = new \AMQPExchange($channel);
$exchange->setName('some_test');
$exchange->setFlags(AMQP_DURABLE);
$exchange->setType(AMQP_EX_TYPE_DIRECT);
$exchange->declareExchange();

$queue = new \AMQPQueue($channel);
$queue->setFlags(AMQP_DURABLE);
$queue->setName('some_test_queue');
$queue->declareQueue();
$queue->bind('some_test', 'some:foo:bar');

$channel->startTransaction();

$exchange->publish('some #1', 'some:foo:bar');
$exchange->publish('some #2', 'some:foo:bar');

$channel->commitTransaction();

$exchange->publish('some #3', 'some:foo:bar');
```

Last messages not published to exchange. But, if I call to `commitTransaction` in channel, last messages was success published to queue.

I read the documentation here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#publisher-confirms

Maybe RabbitMQ after first transaction mark this channel as transactional and always wait commit/rollback after publish any messages?

Answer (score -1):

You should not use Transactions on channel , they are resource heavy , instead you should use something which is a extension to AMQP in the form of Lightweight Publisher Confirms.

They provide same level of guarantee as transactions do but are light on resources and gives you better throughput than transactions.

Refer to it [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html)

Comment: In our case we can use only transactional layer, because at end of logic we pervious commit database transaction and next commit rabbitmq transaction. It's guarantee what the model will be saved on database before we send message to other consumer. If we send message previously, we can have a problem - consumer receive this message but application don't commit database transaction and don't insert model to database. And, in those cases, we can have a case where we must rollback database transaction. Usage transactional layer guarantee what two levels will be rollback or commit both. Thank.